# SAP HANA Vora maven project setup in Eclipse

Tags: hana, vora

I am new to Vora. I am trying to create a Maven project for Vora development.

Can someone guide me with the right pom.xml and the dependencies required to create the Vora project. I read in the documentation that spark-sap-datasources-*.*-assembly.jar is required, but I am unable to find this jar.

I want to do something similar given in the below SAP help URL.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/0991e2320f5940d988ed32b995d28a44/1.3/en-US/dfe39650805e46b2bb5854aadffa11d1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Vora datasource jar file on each node that has Vora deployed. Assuming you have Vora 1.4, it is in folder `/opt/vora/lib/vora-spark/lib/`. You can also search for it, e.g.

```
# find /opt/ -name *datasources*
/opt/vora/lib/vora-spark/lib/spark-sap-datasources-1.4.2.12-vora-1.4-assembly.jar
```